# Athena tables getting dropped on its own

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-athena

I have created athena table using spark sql, like below:

```
    spark.sql("""
     CREATE TABLE dbname.tablename
     using parquet
     options(path 's3_full_path')
    """)
```

The table is getting created, but after around 10 mins it get missing